# Image Capture default action for *any* camera

Tags: snow-leopard, settings, camera, image-capture

I'm trying to implement a solution for a multiuser environment involving Image Capture and AutoImport. (10.6.8 with remote MCX).

Our users often connect digital cameras to our Macs to download the images from them. I'd really like to have the AutoImporter application launch whenever **any camera** is connected.

This kind of behaviour is easily enabled in the Image Capture app. However, these settings seem to be applied *per camera* (by using a UUID for each camera in the ImageCapture plists), not for **any camera** that may be connected.

One solution I've considered; adding the UUIDs for all of the cameras that we have in the department to the MCX preferences for Image Capture. However, aside from being onerous in the short and long-term, this wouldn't provide the desired user experience for those that use their own cameras (cameras we don't have UUIDs for).

I'm interested to see if anyone else has come up against this and how they overcame it. Also, if anyone knows of `.plist` values that can be implemented to provide the behaviour I'm looking for. I'm not limited to using built in software either, but it is very preferential.